# How to go to the next/previous cell in UITableView programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've got UItableview and also two buttons Next and Previous tapping on which I should go to the selection of the previous/next cell? is it possible? Moreover, how to remember the cell the user last tapped so that it is selected on start-up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Implement UITableViewDelegate and save the currently selected index in didSelectRowAtIndexPath:

```
NSIndexPath *currentSelection;

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    currentSelection = indexPath;
}
```

Then in your button action you can do something like...

```
- (IBAction)didTapNextButton:(id)sender{

    //Remember to check boundaries before just setting an indexpath or your app will crash!
    if(currentSelection){
        currentSelection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentSelection.row+1 inSection:currentSelection.section];
    }else{
        currentSelection = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
    }

    [self.tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:currentSelection animated:YES scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPositionTop];

}
```

Comment: didSelectRowAtIndexPath isn't called yet((

Comment: Then you need to choose a starting index in your button action if no selection has been made yet. I've updated the code in my answer to show how that may be done, check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a couple of `UITableView` category methods that can find the next/previous `NSIndexPath` from a specified `NSIndexPath`.

These methods accommodate sections and empty sections.

**@interface (.h)**

```
@interface UITableView(Extensions)
- (NSIndexPath *)nextIndexPathFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
- (NSIndexPath *)prevIndexPathFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
@end
```

**@implementation (.m)**

```
@implementation UITableView(Extensions)
-(NSIndexPath *)nextIndexPathFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self adjacentIndexPathFromIndexPath:indexPath goingForward:YES];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)prevIndexPathFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return [self adjacentIndexPathFromIndexPath:indexPath goingForward:NO];
}

-(NSIndexPath *)adjacentIndexPathFromIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath goingForward:(BOOL)goingForward {
    NSInteger delta = goingForward ? 1 : -1;

    NSInteger adjRow = indexPath.row + delta;

    if (adjRow >= 0 && adjRow < [self numberOfRowsInSection:indexPath.section]) {
        //Adjacent row in same section...
        return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:adjRow inSection:indexPath.section];
    }

    NSInteger adjSection = indexPath.section + delta;

    if (adjSection < 0) {
        adjSection = [self numberOfSections] - 1;
    } else if (adjSection > [self numberOfSections] - 1) {
        adjSection = 0;
    }

    NSUInteger adjSectionRows = [self numberOfRowsInSection:adjSection];

    if (!adjSectionRows) {
        //Adjacent section is empty...
        //Adjacent row in adjacent-adjacent section...
        return [self adjacentIndexPathFromIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:adjSection] goingForward:goingForward];
    }

    adjRow = goingForward ? 0 : adjSectionRows - 1;

    //Adjacent row in adjacent section...
    return [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:adjRow inSection:adjSection];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be just to **keep track** of the selected index.

- Keep track of the selected index.
- On button change the index.
- Reload the table. [tableview reloadData];

All you need to do is expose the selected index through the cellForRowAtIndexPath function:

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.selected = true;
}
```

In regards to the second part I think your referring to state management. If so the **NSUserDefaults** is how I usually do it :)

```
// get 
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"myLastSelectedIndex"]

// set to 5
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:5] forKey:@"myLastSelectedIndex"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the method named scrollToRowAtIndexPath method. And you can store the indexPath whenever cell is selected. So you can restore it when users restarts.

Answer (score 0):

For selecting some cell in tableView, please, use : `- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition` (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).
For index selected storing You may use many ways, but, most useful is:

```
NSUserDefaults* def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[def setObject:selectNum forKay:@"someKay"];
[def synchronize];
```

, I think.

And, in Your case, you better switch off the tableView flag "User Interaction Enabled".